# Angular Firebase retrieve data and use data for another retrieve data (Realtime)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

**(It can't be done in real time as I understand it.)**

I've been dealing with this for about four days but I just couldn't.I need your help.

This is my databasa :https://prnt.sc/v60q8k

```
"users" : {
"biFAvWnJUNX4p3IHyFjHBN8ES3X2" : {
      "bio" : "zzz",
      "birthday" : "2019-09-10",
      "city" : "İstanbul",
      "control" : true,
      "pp" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kamparkadasi.appspot.com/o/images%2Fnew.jpg?alt=media&token=a9541af8-cdbe-41de-a72d-5740f030a361"
      "email" : "zafer@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Zafer",
      "notifications" : {
        "-MKAqcM1EhQoQ489aZM3" : {
          "formId" : "-MK4x-jvo51ZH6eBgnsA",
          "type" : "request",
          "who" : "yMrvene3CcbUMzUrZ5aDttqM4vi1"
        },
        "-MKB-xuHaxvgGAo-0zZG" : {
          "result" : "Reddedildi",
          "type" : "response",
          "who" : "yMrvene3CcbUMzUrZ5aDttqM4vi1"
        },}

}
"yMrvene3CcbUMzUrZ5aDttqM4vi1" : {
         "name" : "pennywise",
         "pp" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kamparkadasi.appspot.com/o/images%2Fnew.jpg?alt=media&token=a9541af8-cdbe-41de-a72d-5740f030a361"
}
}
```

I want to display all notifications with users's **name** and **pp** in html it should work realtime

My code is working but Doesn't work the way I want. What I want doesn't work with array as far as I understand.

```
notifications : Array<any>=[]
this.userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      this.db.database.ref("/users/"+this.userUid+"/notifications/").on("value",snap=>{this.notifications=[],snap.forEach(a=>{
        
         var type = a.child("type").val()
         var userpath = this.db.database.ref("/users/"+a.child("who").val())
         if(type=="request"){
          var formId = a.child("formId").val()
        
           userpath.once("value",x=>{this.notifications.push({notKey:a.key,type:type,name:x.child("name").val(),pp:x.child("pp").val(),who:a.child("who").val(),formId:formId})})
         }
         else if(type=="response"){
       
          userpath.once("value",x=>{this.notifications.push({type:type,name:x.child("name").val(),pp:x.child("pp").val(),who:a.child("who").val(),result:a.child("result").val()})}) 
         }
        })
       })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what the specific problem is.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you want me to put the json file directly?

Comment: @DougStevenson actually I didn't put the code in order not to confuse you.